Xcode 16.0 build Time significantly increased
I'm confused because of Xcode 16.0 build time significantly increased
1st build - 23 min (after updating Xcode)
2nd build - 35 min (without any changes)
3rd build - 34 min (without any changes)
4th build - 23 min (clean build) I got very weird result here :|
This is 5-6 times slower
My mac is M1 pro
Any idea or suggestions? I've not migrated swift 6.0 yet, think It will be slower when compiler starts checking of race conditions.

This is not our problem; you need to tell Apple about it.

I saw ~18-19% build time increase with Xcode 16 compared to 15.4 when building https://github.com/devMEremenko/XcodeBenchmark, not as dramatic but still significant. You should run Product > Perform Action > Build with Timing Summary to see what's taking so long.

A possible explanation is that some modules are built several times, see https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2024/10171/ for details.
